# Use Azure Storage for Multi-Tenant Application Logging and Tracing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

We are working on a multi-tenant web application (ASP.NET, MVC, C#) which is going to host in Azure App Service. Each tenant will have separate DB and separate Azure Storage account for store files. 
I have gone through MSDN article on [Enabling Storage Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log). But according to it  Application Logging on Blob Storage cannot keep per Tenant. 
My question is,

1. Is there a way to configure multiple Blob storages and write log
   entries to them?
2. If not, Is there any way to handle this using code?
3. Is there any logging framework (Nlog, Log4Net etc) support for multiple azure storage accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log into storages linked to tenants you would probably have to handle it in code. E.g. keep track of tenant id in the requests and being able to resolve storage wrapper with appropriate connection string.

I would recommend you to take a look at Azure OMS Log Analytics. Just create log records with tenantId and push it to OMS. All your logs will be at the same place and you'll be able to query logs by tenant (where tenantId=123) or by type e.g. "error".

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/)